# selenium retrieves an error when selecting ID/XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import chromedriver_binary
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]').send_keys(user_name)
```

This is how code looks like (I've tried xpath,id, class name, etc..) but I will ALWAYS get an error

*selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="username"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.87)

I am trying to get this done on [here](https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=cs)

Any ideas please?

Comment: Did you write code to open chrome browser?

Comment: Yes :) browser opens and a while later error shows up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the given form is within Iframe so switch to iframe is required to interact with any element which is within IFrame.

Following code works for me :

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//iframe[@title="Registration form"])[1]'))
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]').send_keys("username")
```

Feel free to use explicit wait if require.

Comment: +1 this one works, thanks for helping me from headache. Would you be able to give me refference of doc you used for contstrucring xpath? I used this https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html# but it seems your syntax is little different..

Comment: Also, I noticed that password field is out of the iframe (and is not included in another one) so I need to switch out of the frame, or something? as I tried to grab xpath for password and same error appears as it was in case of user..

Comment: for anyone else struggling with Selenium in beginnings - YES, you have to switch back to default content from iframe/frame.
Use "driver.switch_to_default_content()"

Comment: @Chris - I wrote xpath based on my experience but you can sure learn more from here : https://devhints.io/xpath , Any yes you need to switch back to default content once you are done with your operation of iframe.